# setState not updating in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple component as follows:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';


function App() {

  const [bus1Points, setBus1Points] = useState();

  const updateBuses = () => {
    setTimeout(updateBuses, 1000);
    console.log(bus1Points);  // Undefined each second
  };

  setInterval(() => {
    console.log('Interval ' + bus1Points); // <-- Prints expected value
  }, 500)

  console.log(bus1Points);
  useEffect(() => {
    setBus1Points('TEST');
    updateBuses();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
      {bus1Points}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm not sure why it's undefined each time. Is this a bug in React? Why would `updateBuses` only get the initial value of `bus1points`? (Note that `bus1points` renders correctly in the UI)

Comment: The state updater is asynchronous and due to closures `updateBuses` captures `bus1Points` before it actually changes

Comment: `setInterval` is defined on the function body and will add a new interval on every re-render(which you should never do). can you elaborate more on what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks Asaf, I'm only seeing this now. I got it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's undefined because state updates are reflected only in next render. When you see it correctly render in UI, it is because ReactJS has already completed another cycle of rendering and updated your state (where `bus1Points` has the new value) and finally renders the correct UI.

Whenever you call `setBus1Points` you're telling react to batch a new state value, but your variable `bus1Points` is just a value, so that's why it does not change.

**Update**

The issue is that when you do

```
const updateBuses = () => {
    setTimeout(updateBuses, 1000);
    console.log(bus1Points);  // Undefined each second
  };
```

You're capturing the value of `bus1Points` (with a closure) in the first render. Given the initial value of `bus1Points` is `undefined`, you will always log that value. That's because `updateBuses` references a variable that's outside of its definition, so it "captures" that value, and it is called everytime through the recursive `setTimeout`.

Your `setInterval`, however, is being executed on every render, so you're capturing the new value of `bus1Points` (And you're also adding everytime more and more logs, generating a memory leak). This is *not* a recursive function so it captures in each render the new value.

Comment: Sure, I understand that they are asynchronous, but this value is undefined even way after I initially set it. I expect it to be undefined the first time, but not after 1 second.

Comment: this is because you're referencing in your setTimeout, by a closure, the same initial variable, which still holds the initial value (`undefined`). The `console.log(bus1Points);` that's before your effect (outside of any function, on the component's render level) should be logging the value correctly

Comment: See this example which explains the same behavior as your snippet https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/#second-attempt

Comment: Please see my updated code snippet. I added a `setInterval` on the component's render level and it actually prints the expected value.

Comment: It's much more clear, thank you. I'm having trouble fixing it though, I'll let you know if I get the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204585/discussion-between-dara-java-and-gonzalo).